# How do I get the Ubuntu source code?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system

Where can I find the source code for the latest Ubuntu release?

Also, how would I view the code? Would it just be lots of .cpp and .h files I could view in Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks, was i right going for the dists subfolder? At this point i was presented with a massive number of sub-folders? Are each of these part of the OS?

Comment: Subset of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106818/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-source-code

Answer (score 20):

The source code for ubuntu is divided up by package - from a running ubuntu system you can easily retreive the source for any package by doing:

```
apt-get source (package name)
```

Otherwise, go to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu), and search up the package in question. For example, here's the download page for the source code for a specific version of curl: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/7.21.2-4ubuntu1

That said, it's a lot easier if you're on a Linux system already - the package sources are divided into an original source tarball plus ubuntu patches, so if you don't use `apt-get source`, you'll need to manually apply the patch to the source code. And new-style packages are even divided into multiple packages.

What's more, the packages are generally not designed to be cross-compiled from a non-Linux system. Even if you download them and open them in VS, you won't be able to build them from a Windows system.

Finally, note that not everything is in C and C++ - there are packages in just about any language you can imagine. But I suppose most of them could be opened in VS as text files :)

Note: If you really, **really** want all of it, and I can't stress enough how silly it would be to download *everything* just to start learning about the system, you can use the `debmirror` tool, available in ubuntu, to do this:

```
debmirror -a none \
          --source \
          -s main \
          -d lucid,lucid-security,lucid-updates \
          -r /ubuntu \ 
          --progress \
          -e http \
          -h archive.ubuntu.com \ ## or other ubuntu archive mirror
          destpath
```

This will be an absolutely huge download. Have several tens of GBs of space available. Note that this downloads only core packages - replace `-s main` with `-s main,universe,multiverse,restricted` to get everything.

Once you have the package files, you can extract the source by running `dpkg-source -x` on a .dsc file of interest.

Comment: Is there anyway to just get them all, as i cant really say i know which 'packages' i want? Im just interested in learning how Linux as an operating system works

Comment: Getting them all will just overwhelm you - we're talking about gigabytes here. I'd recomment starting with an installed ubuntu system, playing around with the shell, and when you find something you're interested in knowing more about, using apt-get source on it.

Comment: Maybe you should add that the sources are downloaded into the current working directory.

Answer (score 7):

1. [archive.ubuntu.com](http://archive.ubuntu.com)
2. Most of them are .c and .h files (not sure about C++), but certainly not all (some perl, some Python, etc). There will also be a lot of documentation files that aren't saved with .txt, just like `README` and `LICENSE`.

Answer (score -2):

You can pick the source image from here (16.04 in this case):
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/source/

You can also choose the version you want.

Reference:
https://askubuntu.com/a/167472

Comment: in my case, i want THE SOURCE CODE, NOT THE IMAGE